# Get a list of distinct values in Javascript List

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, loops, distinct

Essentially I have a list of objects with an output as follows:

```
  [
    {
      "eventDate": "August 15, 2022 at 9:00 AM",
      "title":        "Dr.",
      "first_name":   "Jane",
      "last_name":    "Doe"
    },
    {
      "eventDate": "August 15, 2022 at 1:00 AM",
      "title":        "Dr.",
      "first_name":   "Jane",
      "last_name":    "Doe"
    }
  ]
```

Essentially as you can see above, the results are almost identical with the exception of the time listed in the `eventDate`. The time for me does not make a difference and I would like to eliminate the duplicate entries which are essentially identical, just like the above, the only thing that is okay for not having to match is the time.

The data is saved as a string in the database it is stored in so it is not as simple as changing the date format. Hence what I did so far is as follows (for the first entry):

```
var fullDate = res.items[0].sessionStartTime
console.log(fullDate);

var month = fullDate.split(' ')[0];
var day = fullDate.split(' ')[1];
var year = fullDate.split(' ')[2];
var newDate = month + " " + day + " " + year

var formattedDate = new Date(newDate).toDateString();
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Which outputs the `formattedDate` as follows: `Mon Aug 15 2022`

What I want to do is convert each of the `eventDate` entries in the array to the new date format output. Hence it will look as follows:

```
  newArray = 
  [
    {
      "eventDate": "Mon Aug 15 2022",
      "title":        "Dr.",
      "first_name":   "Jane",
      "last_name":    "Doe"
    },
    {
      "eventDate": "Mon Aug 15 2022",
      "title":        "Dr.",
      "first_name":   "Jane",
      "last_name":    "Doe"
    }
  ]
```

Hence this way I can find the distinct values for `eventDate` by making use of:

```
const unique = [...new Map(newArray.map((m) => [m.eventDate, m])).values()];
```

Which should output:

```
  unique = 
  [
    {
      "eventDate": "Mon Aug 15 2022",
      "title":        "Dr.",
      "first_name":   "Jane",
      "last_name":    "Doe"
    }
  ]
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

My Actual list of objects is:

```
[
    {
      formField7: "Test",
      amountDue: "Test",
      serviceType: "Course",
      staffMember: "Test",
      formField2: "Test",
      formResponse2: "-",
      formResponse7: "Test",
      formField6: "Test",
      formField10: "Test",
      paymentStatus: "Test",
      formField1: "Test",
      dateOfBooking: "Test",
      _id: "Test",
      _owner: "Test",
      _createdDate: "Test",
      serviceName: "Test",
      formField8: "Test",
      paymentMethod: "Test",
      groupSize: "1",
      formField4: "Test",
      formResponse1: "Test",
      formField5: "Test",
      _updatedDate: "Test",
      formResponse5: "Test",
      eventDate: "August 15, 2022 at 9:00 AM",
      formResponse8: "Test",
      couponName: "Test",
      formResponse0: "Test",
      formResponse11: "Test",
      clientEmail: "Test",
      formField9: "Test",
      attendanceStatus: "Test",
      sessionDuration: "Test",
      formField3: "Test",
      formResponse4: "-",
      clientAddress: "-",
      formResponse9: "Test",
      clientName: "Jane Doe",
      formField11: "Test",
      formResponse6: "Test",
      formField0: "Test",
      bookingStatus: "Test",
      clientPhoneNumber: "Test",
      amountPaid: "Test",
      formResponse10: "Test",
      formResponse3: "Test"
    },
    {
      formField7: "Test",
      amountDue: "Test",
      serviceType: "Course",
      staffMember: "Test",
      formField2: "Test",
      formResponse2: "-",
      formResponse7: "Test",
      formField6: "Test",
      formField10: "Test",
      paymentStatus: "Test",
      formField1: "Test",
      dateOfBooking: "Test",
      _id: "Test",
      _owner: "Test",
      _createdDate: "Test",
      serviceName: "Test",
      formField8: "Test",
      paymentMethod: "Test",
      groupSize: "1",
      formField4: "Test",
      formResponse1: "Test",
      formField5: "Test",
      _updatedDate: "Test",
      formResponse5: "Test",
      eventDate: "August 15, 2022 at 1:00 AM",
      formResponse8: "Test",
      couponName: "Test",
      formResponse0: "Test",
      formResponse11: "Test",
      clientEmail: "Test",
      formField9: "Test",
      attendanceStatus: "Test",
      sessionDuration: "Test",
      formField3: "Test",
      formResponse4: "-",
      clientAddress: "-",
      formResponse9: "Test",
      clientName: "Jane Doe",
      formField11: "Test",
      formResponse6: "Test",
      formField0: "Test",
      bookingStatus: "Test",
      clientPhoneNumber: "Test",
      amountPaid: "Test",
      formResponse10: "Test",
      formResponse3: "Test"
    }
]
```

This is being outputted as a JSON after a query is ran on a database.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to

1. Loop through the array,
2. convert the date,
3. add the event to an object, by creating a unique property based on all properties in the event, and
4. convert the object to an array

```js
let events = [
    {
      "eventDate": "August 15, 2022 at 9:00 AM",
      "title":        "Dr.",
      "first_name":   "Jane",
      "last_name":    "Doe"
    },
    {
      "eventDate": "August 15, 2022 at 1:00 AM",
      "title":        "Dr.",
      "first_name":   "Jane",
      "last_name":    "Doe"
    }
  ]
  
function convertDate(eventDateStr) {                 // 2
  let parser = /(\w+) (\d+), (\d+) at (\d+:\d+) (\w+)/;
  let [fullMatch, fullMonth, day, fullYear, time, hour12] = parser.exec(eventDateStr)
  let formattedDate = new Date(`${fullMonth} ${day} ${fullYear}`).toDateString();

  return formattedDate
}

function getUniqueItems(eventsArr) {
  let eventsObj = {},
      uniqueEventsArr = [],
      stringifiedProperty = '';
  
  for (let event of eventsArr) {                     // 1
    event.eventDate = convertDate(event.eventDate);  // 2
    stringifiedProperty = JSON.stringify(event);     // 3
    eventsObj[stringifiedProperty] = event;          // 3
  }
  
  for (let property in eventsObj) {                  // 4
    uniqueEventsArr.push(eventsObj[property]);
  }
  
  return uniqueEventsArr
}

console.log(getUniqueItems(events))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and help! I tried making use of my actual list which has much more data in the list which I updated my answer to reflect however the following error is being outputted and does not seem to work with my array of objects: 
`Error: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method `

Comment: You need to debug in order to locate the problem (check the row number), but it could be the array deconstruct inside `convertDate()`

Comment: the convertDate() works fine when done on one entry.   console.log(convertDate(eventsArr[0].eventDate))